# look for the image by caputura of screen, even if it is not in that moment

Tags: python, pyautogui

What code could I use if I want to look for the image, even if it is not at that moment, but when it is found? My code would be:

```
import pyautogui as auto
import time
import pyautogui


def Saludar (seconds,schedule) :

    while (1>0) and (schedule == True) :
        time.sleep(seconds)

        x, y = auto.locateCenterOnScreen('linea.png', grayscale=True)
        auto.moveTo(x,y)
        pyautogui.click()
        print("YA")



if __name__== "__main__":
    Saludar(2,True)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mario/Desktop/buscar aun si no está.py", line 19, in <module>
    Saludar(2,True)
  File "C:/Users/mario/Desktop/buscar aun si no está.py", line 11, in Saludar
    x, y = auto.locateCenterOnScreen('linea.png', grayscale=True)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `auto.locateCenterOnScreen('linea.png', grayscale=True)` is returning `None`. Are you sure `linea.png` exists?

Comment: yes it exists, but if there is something superimposed on it or it is not in that moment, it does not continue looking for it!! How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When the image is not found it would raise a `TypeError` Exception. You can simply handle that with a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions):

```
import pyautogui as auto
import time
import pyautogui


def Saludar(seconds, schedule):
    while (1 > 0) and (schedule == True):
        time.sleep(seconds)
        try:
            x, y = auto.locateCenterOnScreen(
                'Desktop/linea.png', grayscale=True)
            print('Found it!')
            auto.moveTo(x, y)
            pyautogui.click()
        except TypeError:
            """
            Image is not found
            """
            print("Image is Not found on the screen!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Saludar(2, True)
```